# Pick data from array

Tags: python, loops

I have array data, (T). T is temperature as function of time (t) and height (h). I want to pick values of T in the particular height, for example, in 100 km height and then plot it in 2D graphic. 
Why this loop didn't work?

```
for j in range(len(tim1)):
    for i in range(len(height1)):
        if height1 == 350. :
            print(i,j,T)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

    if height1 == 350. :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: can u share ur some sample data

Comment: is this numpy?  also that error message seems fairly self-explanatory...  `height1` is an array, `==` in numpy produces an array of booleans, and you can't test that result for truthiness directly.

Comment: er, also, you aren't actually testing `T` anywhere here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have misinterpreted the question, but you may just need to make sure you are indexing the list when you test for the condition:

```
for j in range(len(tim1)):
    for i in range(len(height1)):
        if height1[i] == 350. :
            print(i,j,T)
```